# Grouping list to sublist with Linq

Tags: c#

I have list of objects that loaded from csv file, my goal is write it to xml and download it.

here is original csv file data like this:

```
A  1  str1 1001
A  1  str2 1002
A  1  str2 1003
B  2  str3 1004
B  2  str3 1005
```

And output xml dta should look like this:

```
<MyHeader>
   <columnHeader1 foo='A' order='1'>
      <columnHeader2 title="str1">
         <columnHeader3 id="1001"/>
      </columnHeader2>
      <columnHeader2 title="str2">
          <columnHeader3 id="1002" />
          <columnHeader3 id="1003" />
      </columnHeader2>
   </columnHeader1>
<columnHeader1 foo='B' order='2'>
      <columnHeader2 title="str3">
         <columnHeader3 id="1004"/>
         <columnHeader3 id="1005"/>
      </columnHeader2>
   </columnHeader1>
...
```

here is model defination

```
public class foo
    {
        public string letter { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string titleid { get; set; }
    }
```

how can I prepeare this xml file with list of models above ?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this, but what have you attempted to do before asking this question? How did you read form the CSV file? How did you attempt to write the XML? Maybe we can help you where you got stuck if that is the case.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at csv helper: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ -- this will allow you to iterate the records in your csv doc, at which point you can box them as your "foo" class, add them into a list. Then query, group, output. But I'm with Dandre here, what have done so far?

Comment: @Dandré I just need to write list of foo to xmk file like above, I already read and load data to list.  I am using simple xmlserializer but my data format must be like above..

Comment: @PimBrouwers I think I need to seperate title and titleid to 'bar' class and add list of it as property to foo ('List<bar> barlits{get; set;}') you mean this?

Comment: TyForHelpDude, so do you not know how to serialize something to XML, or did you try a couple of things but it didn't work? Because there are many options to serialize an object to XML: XML Serializer, XML Document object (and then calling Save on it), even just plain old writing the XML in a String and then writing it to a file will work (but least preferred).

Comment: Generate a complete and valid XML sample and let VS design the classes for you http://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/ - fill the structure and serialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is sorted in the following manner: letter => title => id

The simplest solution could be to just use a loop and a StringBuilder to concatenate strings:

```
StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
string letter = string.Empty;
string title = string.Empty;

xmlBuilder.Append("<MyHeader>");

foreach (foo item in foos)
{
    if (title != string.Empty && item.title != title)
    {
        xmlBuilder.Append("</columnHeader2>");
    }

    if (letter != string.Empty && item.letter != letter)
    {
        xmlBuilder.Append("</columnHeader1>");
    }

    if (item.letter != letter)
    {
        letter = item.letter;
        xmlBuilder.AppendFormat("<columnHeader1 foo='{0}' order='{1}'>", item.letter, item.order);
    }

    if (item.title != title)
    {
        title = item.title;
        xmlBuilder.AppendFormat("<columnHeader2 title=\"{0}\">", item.tile);
    }

    xmlBuilder.AppendFormat("<columnHeader3 id=\"{0}\" />", item.titleid)
}

xmlBuilder.Append("</columnHeader2>");
xmlBuilder.Append("</columnHeader1>");
xmlBuilder.Append("</MyHeader>");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though this is simple and effective for your current solution, have a look anyway at XML Serialization. It will save you a lot of time in adding another field to your XML as opposed to looking at the strings and figuring out which string needs to change because of the extra field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to group the data. To make this code work I have renamed your `foo` type `Foo` which allows me to have variables named `foo`. The variable `foos` is a collection of `Foo` objects.

```
var groupedData = from foo in foos
                  group foo by new { foo.letter, foo.order } into outerGroup
                  from innerGroup in
                       (from foo in outerGroup
                        group foo by foo.title)
                  group innerGroup by outerGroup.Key;
```

As you can see the sequence is first grouped the composite key `letter` and `order` and then within each outer group the `Foo` objects are grouped by `title`.

By using LINQ to XML you can then convert the grouped data into hierarchical XML:

```
var root = new XElement(
  "MyHeader",
  groupedData.Select(
    outerGroup => new XElement(
      "columnHeader1",
      new XAttribute("foo", outerGroup.Key.letter),
      new XAttribute("order", outerGroup.Key.order),
      outerGroup.Select(
        innerGroup => new XElement(
          "columnHeader2",
          new XAttribute("title", innerGroup.Key),
          innerGroup.Select(
            foo => new XElement(
              "columnHeader3",
              new XAttribute("id", foo.titleid)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```